# Bounds for $\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find upper and lower bounds for $\displaystyle\frac{x-y}{x+y}$? So I do see that

$$\frac{x-y}{x+y} = \frac{1}{x+y}\cdot(x-y) = \frac{x}{x+y} - \frac{y}{x+y} > \frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{1}{x+y} = \frac{0}{x+y} = 0$$

(is it correct?) but I don't get how to find the upper bound.

Comment: Do you have any restriction on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: This is false. How do you know $x>1$? And if $y>1$, you only have $-\dfrac y{x+y}\color{red}<\dfrac1{x+y}$.

Comment: No restrictions

Comment: no bounds then I would say! you could simply fix $y$ and play around with $x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x = 1-y$. For these pairs, $\frac{x-y}{x+y} = 1-2y$ and we have $\mbox{lim}_{y\rightarrow \pm\infty}(1-2y) = \mp \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\dfrac{x-y}{x+y} = c$, where $c \neq -1$.

Then

$$\begin{eqnarray}
 x - y &=& c(x + y) \\
 x - cx &=& y + cy \\
 (1 - c)x &=& (1 + c)y
\end{eqnarray}$$

Therefore $y = \dfrac{1-c}{1+c} x$.

But if $\dfrac{x-y}{x+y} = -1$, then $x - y = -1(x + y)$,
and from this we conclude that $x = 0$ and $y$ can be anything you want.

So you can set $\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}$ to any value you like by choosing
suitable values of $x$ and $y$. There are no limits on $\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}$.

Answer (score 2):

so we have $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$, we want to show that $f(x,y)$ is unbounded, therefore we fix $y=y_0>0$ and then have

$$
f(x,y_0)=f(x)=\frac{x-y_0}{x+y_0}
$$

now choose $x=x^*-y_0$ which gives us
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^*-2y_0}{x^*}
$$
and now observe that for $\lim_{x^*\to0+}\frac{x^*-2y_0}{x^*}=-\infty$ and for $\lim_{x^*\to0-}\frac{x^*-2y_0}{x^*}=\infty$.

So $f(x,y)$ is indeed unbounded as we thought.